# ERunactions is not working - Yii

Tags: jquery, yii, background, yii-extensions

I'm trying to send mail as a background process using ERunactions of Yii extension, but it does not work.

```
public function actionTimeConsumingProcess()
    {       
        ERunActions::touchUrl($this->createAbsoluteUrl('test/SendMail'),null,null,array());
}
```

**SendMail method :**

```
public function actionSendMail()
    {

          yii::import('application.extensions.smtpmail.PHPMailer');
        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        try{
        $dmmodel = DeliveryMethodModel::model()->findByPk(7);

        $mail->Host =$dmmodel->host;// "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Username= $dmmodel->username;
        $mail->Password= $dmmodel->password;
        $mail->Mailer='smtp';
        $mail->Port=$dmmodel->port;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = ($dmmodel->smtp_enableSSL==1?'ssl':($dmmodel->smtp_enableSSL==2 ? 'tls':''));


        $mail->From = $dmmodel->email_from;
        $mail->FromName = $dmmodel->name_from;       
        $mail->Subject    = "Mail Configuration : Test Mail";
        $mail->MsgHTML("This is an e-mail message sent automatically");
        $mail->AddAddress($dmmodel->email_from, $dmmodel->name_from);
        $mail->AddAddress($dmmodel->default_TO);

        $mail->IsHTML(true);  
     $mail->Send();
     // if(!$mail->Send()) {
            echo "Msg sent";
        //}else {
        }
        catch (phpmailerException $e)
        {
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $e->errorMessage();
       }    

    }
```

**ajax code to call the controller action,**

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php  echo  CController::createUrl('operator/TimeConsumingProcess'); ?>",  


            success: function(data){
}
});
```

No error showing in application.log, please can anyone help me why its not working ?

Comment: Please can anyone help me to sort this issue

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not complete (like there is no view code or model used in SendMail), so I can't say what is the exact problem, but in general your example is working.

I was able to put together a small working app based on it, hope it will be useful.

You can find the full code on [github](https://github.com/serebrov/yii-test-runactions).

Controller code:

```
<?php

Yii::import('ext.runactions.components.ERunActions');

class TestController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * This is the default 'index' action that is invoked
     * when an action is not explicitly requested by users.
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::log('action: Index', 'error');
        // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
        // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
        $this->render('index');
    }

    public function actionTimeConsumingProcess()
    {
        Yii::log('action: TimeConsumingProcess', 'error');
        ERunActions::touchUrl(
            $this->createAbsoluteUrl('test/SendMail'),null,null,array()
        );
        echo json_encode(array('status'=>'ok'));
    }

    public function actionSendMail()
    {
        Yii::log('action: SendMail', 'error');
    }

}
```

View code:

```
<h1>Welcome to the TEST PAGE</h1>

<p>Run the test <a class="run-test" href="#">run</a>.</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.run-test').click(function() {
    alert('run');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php  echo  CController::createUrl('test/TimeConsumingProcess'); ?>",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

What the code does is:

- Index action renders the `index` view with `run` link
- The `run` link launches ajax call to the `test/TimeConsumingProcess`
- The `actionTimeConsuminProcess` invokes `actionSendMail`
- All actions are logged to the application log file `protected/runtime/application.log`

The log file looks like this:

```
2016/01/13 00:51:48 [error] [application] action: Index
in /home/seb/web/yii-test-runactions/app/protected/controllers/TestController.php (14)
in /home/seb/web/yii-test-runactions/app/index.php (13)
2016/01/13 00:51:51 [error] [application] action: TimeConsumingProcess
in /home/seb/web/yii-test-runactions/app/protected/controllers/TestController.php (22)
in /home/seb/web/yii-test-runactions/app/index.php (13)
2016/01/13 00:51:51 [error] [application] action: SendMail
in /home/seb/web/yii-test-runactions/app/protected/controllers/TestController.php (31)
in /home/seb/web/yii-test-runactions/app/index.php (13)
```

You can see that all three actions were invoked.

Also note, that you have some `echo` statements in the `SendMail` action. You will not see them unless you call the send mail action directly (like http://mysite/controller/sendmail).

You can actually do this to make sure the send mail works, but to test it together with runactions it is better to use Yii::log(...) to have the debug data in the application.log.

Answer (score -2):

First of all read all code from top to bottom, if all good, then try the same code to another system with fresh software installs.

Hopefully it will be beneficial for you.